# XSLT practice example

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm studying for an exam, and I'd like to make sure I'munderstanding this correctly. Would the following print out ABC or just BC because the templates weren't applied to next/previous/item?

input.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<next>
    <previous>
        <item>A</item>
    </previous>
    <item>B</item>
    <item>C</item>
</next>
```

input.xsl :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <HowDoes>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="next/item" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="previous/item" />
        </HowDoes>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="item">
        <ThisWork>
            <xsl:copy-of select="." />
        </ThisWork>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Take a look here: http://xsltcake.com/slices/EeAoyt

Comment: Thats an awesome tool; thanks!

Comment: I hope you haven't been taught to write your XML without indentation?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your stylesheet will ignore `A` because, from the standpoint of the root of the document (where your first template matches), there are two `next/item` nodes but *no* `previous/item` nodes. Only a `next/previous/item` node.

If you changed your template to

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <HowDoes>
      <xsl:apply-templates select=".//item" />
    </HowDoes>
</xsl:template>
```

then all `item` nodes would be found, as it is looking for all `item` *descendants* of the current node, instead of all `item` children of `previous` children.